# How to connect Prisma and migrate AWS ebs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, prisma

After deploying successfully my nodejs app to AWS elastic beanstalk, I could open it on postman and check my routes, although it was all working correctly, from ebs logs, I could see a javascript error: `Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL.`

so it seems that my app on AWS doesn't have a DATABASE_URL environment to load on my Prisma/schema.prisma file.

on the other hand, I discovered that AWS does provide database connection details through `proccess.env` as follows here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-nodejs.rds.html#nodejs-rds-create

but I have no clue how can I connect to my database on AWS when it's in production but with my .env DATABASE_URL when it's in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add your DATABASE_URL env variable in the Elastic Bean Stalk environment.

1. In your environment select the `Configuration` option from the sidebar.

[image]

2. Click on Software Category and select `Edit` from `Actions` menu.

[image]

3. Add your environment variables (DATABASE_URL) in this case in the `Environment Properties` section and click on Apply.

Now your app should be able to access DATABASE_URL through `process.env.DATABASE_URL` variable.

[image]